# Расчет времени от введенной даты рождения по текущее время

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть задача сделать форму с текстовым полем и кнопкой. В текстовое поле пользователь вводит дату рождения в формате дд.мм.гггг. Далее нужно рассчитать сколько секунд, минут, и часов прожил человек по текущее время.

Я не могу разобраться с тем что, как мне отдельно получать день, месяц и год для расчетов?

Вот мой код:

```html
function calcDate(form) {
  var DOB = form.addDate.value;
  var checkDOB = DOB.match(/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/);
  if (!checkDOB) {
      alert("Введите в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ (например, 25.05.1980)");

     }
  else {
      
     }
}
```

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
        <p>
            Введите дату вашего рождения: <input type="text" name="addDate">
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Рассчитать" onclick="calcDate(form)">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Почитайте про Date() класс например http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp и ещё обьекты даты можно складывать и вычитать.

Comment: А какой смысл высчитывать минуты и секунды, если исходные данные вводятся с точностью всего лишь до дня?

Comment: Хорошо, как дни посчитать? Ведь с инпута я получаю например 12.12.2012, и это есть как целая строка. А как мне взять по отдельности например год, месяц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если наглядно то можно так :

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var birthday = $('#birthday').val();
  var date1 = new Date(birthday);
  var date2 = new Date();
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  
  var diffDays = Math.round(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
  
  var diffHours = diffDays * 24 
  
  var diffMin = diffHours * 60; 
  
  var diffSec = diffMin * 60; 
  
  console.log(diffDays);
  console.log(diffHours);
  console.log(diffMin);
  console.log(diffSec);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='date' id='birthday' format="dd/MM/yyyy"><button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "01.10.2016"; // исходная строка
var birthDate = new Date(str.replace(/^(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)$/, "$3-$2-$1")); //дата
var currentDate = new Date();  //текущая дата
alert( Math.floor( (currentDate - birthDate) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) ); // количество дней
```